# C nested pass by reference memory errors

Tags: c

**The Goal**

Here is what I am trying to do, I want to create a list of users and fill all there information with default values. Then I want to pass that list to a function that will loop through all users and parse each one into a large string of data to return to the user.

**The Error**

When I am looping through the array of structures none of the values are getting added to the string properly. I am new to c but I know that I am not handling my memory correctly somewhere inside the reference calls. And yes I do want to pass all my values by reference, It is needed for other code I am working on this is just a simplified version of the problem I am having.

**The Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// A simple struct to hold user data
struct user_data
{

  int id;
  int age;

};

// Fill the user with blank information
struct user_data get_blank_user()
{

  struct user_data temp_user;
  temp_user.id = 0;    
  temp_user.age = 0;
  return temp_user;

}

// Turn a structure into a string
void user_struct_to_string(struct user_data *input_user, char **return_data)
{

  // Hold the user id and age
  char user_id[10];
  char user_age[10];

  // print the data into the char arrays
  sprintf(user_id, "{%d,", input_user->id);
  sprintf(user_age, "%d}", input_user->age);

  // Clear all data that was inside the string
  memset(*return_data, 0, sizeof(return_data));

  // copy all the data into the return data
  strcat(*return_data, user_id);
  strcat(*return_data, user_age);

}    

// Turn a array of structures into a large string
void get_all_users_string(struct user_data **input_users, int number_of_users, char **return_data)
{

  char *string_holder = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  int i;

  // Loop through all users and add there string of data to the list
  for(i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++)
  {
    // If you are not the first user add a comma before you add to the string
    if (i > 0)
      strcat(*return_data, ",\0");

    // ERROR here after first loop
    user_struct_to_string(&input_users[i], &string_holder);

    // Add the current users string data to the return data
    strcat(*return_data, string_holder);

  }

}

int main()
{

  int i;
  int number_of_users = 10;
  char *user_string = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));

  // Create a dynamic array of users
  struct user_data *users = malloc(number_of_users * sizeof(struct user_data));

  // Fill each user with blank data
  for(i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++)
    users[i] = get_blank_user();

  // Print out a test to prove the function works
  user_struct_to_string(&users[4], &user_string);
  printf("User struct as string: %s\n", user_string);

  // Print user data for test
  for(i = 0; i < number_of_users; i++)
    printf("User id: %d\tUser age: %d\n", users[i].id, users[i].age);

  // Parse all users data into one string
  get_all_users_string(&users, number_of_users, &user_string);
  printf("End string: %s\n", user_string);

  return 0;
}
```

**The Result**

```
User struct as string: {0,0}
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
User id: 0      User age: 0
End string: {0,0}{26071328,0},{1879764480,-943433287},{925474080,32764},{0,0},{4196752,0},{1587521584,32641},{0,0},{925474088,32764},{0,1},{4196429,0}
```

As always thank you anyone who takes the time to read/help with the thread.

Comment: Didn't your compiler complain about this line `user_struct_to_string(&input_users[i], &string_holder);`? The types for the first argument don't match here.

Comment: yes my compiler did complain i just couldnt figure out what it was trying to tell me since all it said was incompatible pointer type. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue with your code is the line -

```
user_struct_to_string(&input_users[i], &string_holder);
```

The function expects a `struct user_data*`, but you are passing `struct user_data**`. The compiler should have warned you about this. You can check the warnings.

Anyway, to fix it you can change the line to -

```
user_struct_to_string(&((*input_users)[i]), &string_holder);
```

You can see the working demo on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/TnO2Lj).

Comment: Thanks a tun I knew there was something small I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

This will not do what you expect:

```
memset(*return_data, 0, sizeof(return_data));
```

`sizeof` will evaluate to the pointer size, not the size of the string. You will need to pass the length of the string to that function.

You should also use `strncat` and pass the length of `return_data`.

Also replace `sprintf` by `snprintf` and pass the length of `user_id`.

Comment: Actually funnily it would work, because he justs needs the first character to be zeroed. But yes, it doesn't do what he expects.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! There are so many things in c that is still dont know. If by any chance you feel up for sending me a site that has some good information on memory management i would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here but to avoid this being to lengthy I will
try to point you in the right direction.

The second argument to user_struct_to_string should be char* because
you allocate the string outside the function before calling it.

```
void user_struct_to_string(struct user_data*, char* );
```

having `char**` would only be needed if you allocate the string inside 
user_struct_to_string() in order to return the address of that newly 
allocated string to the caller.

so the call would be

```
user_struct_to_string(&input_users[i], string_holder);
```

(it would be wise to pass the max length to the function as well to avoid
going pass the size of what string_holder points to)

Inside your function you write

```
memset(*return_data, 0, sizeof(return_data));
```

which doesn't do what you want, sizeof(return_data) - in the original case
when it was was a char** gives the size of the pointer, not the length of the
allocated string. That is why it is handy to pass the max length of the 
allocated string to the function.

```
void user_struct_to_string(struct user_data*, char* return_data, size_t maxLen )
{
...
  memset(return_data, 0, maxLen); 
...
}
```

Although even better would be to just set the first byte string_holder to \0
and then pass it to the function

BTW You create to arrays with user_id and user_age, why not directly write 
it into the string you want to return?

```
void user_struct_to_string(struct user_data*, char* return_data )
{
...
  sprintf( return_data, "{%d,%d}", input_user->id, input_user->age);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice i really do appreciate it! I am always thankful for any extra help.  If by any chance you feel up for sending me a site that has some good information on memory management i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Oh also great idea on combining my two variables into one string print out! Don't know how I let that one slip by me.